# Как держать пользователя залогиненым в приложении android?

Tags: android

У меня есть приложение на андроид, в котором есть простенькая форма логина для доступа ко всем функциям приложения. И вот при вводе логина и пароля я соответственно могу дальше пользоваться приложением, но вот стоит мне свернуть мое приложение или закрыть его то нужно опять повторно логинится, я уже добавил `checkbox` запомнить пароль и логин но эта функция как-то не очень помогает, у меня сложилось впечатление что она не работает. Вот к примеру есть много сервисов с подобной функцией разные социальные программы, или тот же Google Chrome. Я как себе представляю этот функционал( возможно не очень правильно или вообще не правильно) при логине мы отправляем на сервер запрос в котором есть логин и пароль, и в ответ, если все хорошо, должен приходить удачный ответ с токенами, вот я думаю что нужно как-то сохранять пароль и логин на устройстве и при повторном запуске приложения, нам нужно как-то незаметно слать запрос на сервер, опять получать токены для работы. Но мне не очень понятно как это все провернуть, в том плане что

- как отследить обычное сворачивание
- закрытие приложения,

и самое непонятное, это

- как сохранить на локальном хранилище пароль и логин для повторного входа.

Если кто-то уже занимался таким вопросом то я буду очень благодарен за ценные советы и любую полезную информацию. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> как отследить обычное сворачивание и закрытие приложения

Слышали про жизненный цикл [активностей](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity)/[фрагментов](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment)? `onPause`/`onStop`/`onResume`/`onStart` самое то, что вам нужно.

> как сохранить на локальном хранилище пароль и логин для повторного входа

Пароли в чистом виде хранить, я думаю, не стоит, и тем более передавать на сервер. Но в любом случае вариантов масса — `SharedPreferences`, куча баз данных на любой вкус.

> нужно как-то незаметно слать запрос на сервер, опять получать токены для работы

Это уже будет зависеть от того, каким образом у вас будет устроена аутентификация. Самый простой вариант (который у вас наверняка и реализован) — вход по логину и паролю, без `OAuth2`, сессий и всего такого прочего.

Обычно (опять же, в самом простом варианте) юзеры логинятся через свою систему, через соцсети/гугл или что-то ещё, после удачного логина появляется идентифицирующая информация, которая точно говорит о том, что юзер вошёл (`id` в соцсети, почта гугла и т.п.) — вы её сохраняете в локальном хранилище (любым удобным способом) и при следующем входе проверяете, сохранены ли эти данные, если нет — юзер ещё не логинился.

При более сложном варианте можно хранить ещё дату последнего получения этих данных, при их устаревании вручную обновлять их запросами на сервер, спрашиванием юзера либо как-то ещё.

Comment: а если не в чистом виде хранить то я так понял нужно будет как-то шифровать, или что-то в этом роде. Не очень понятен последний пункт вашего ответа, насколько я понял после того как я вошел, например, дальше я получил id пользователя, и сохранил, дальше при повторном запуске я проверяю эту переменную, и что мне дальше делать после проверки? типа миновать экран логина если на устройстве есть уже такой пользователь? тогда как ему подтянуть токены для доступа к информации?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko да, если айди сохранен, то юзер в системе и минуете все логины. Подтянуть токены можете запросами в фоне, если это необходимо. Хранить не в чистом виде — значит хранить, например, хеш, по которому сам пароль восстановить не получится.

Comment: а как вы считаете, целесообразно ли будет использовать сервис для того что-бы как-то сохранить этот id?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko сохранение подразумевает либо использование `SharedPreferences`, либо какой-нибудь базы данных. Это действие занимает несколько миллисекунд и я не думаю, что есть смысл выносить эту задачу в отдельный сервис.

Answer (score 2):

2 подхода:

1. **Обычный** - хранить данные аутентификации в памяти апликейшена и при старте всегда стучаться в сервер на предмет: я такой-то, хочу залогиниться.

Сервер отвечает либо залогинен успешно (продолжаем сессию, либо открываем новую), либо ошибка (данные кривые).

2. **Адекватный** - Сервис. При старте приложение биндит сервис (bound service - у него lifetime больше, чем у activity), а уже тот, получая данные от активити,  логинится и хранит данные оперативно (более безопасно). Также сервис управляет истечением таймаута сессии (если есть) и разрывами соединения, уведомляя активити о необходимости перелогиниться, например.

Но нужно быть аккуратным, тк есть соблазн вместо bound service сделать started service, который тушится чуть сложнее, будучи не остановленным жрёт батарею, и вообще нужен далеко не всегда. Помните, что активити - для пользователя, быстрая и красивая. Сервис - для программиста, обменивается данными и не падает, нужно проектировать так, чтобы не было uncaught exceptions.

Comment: я прочитал про сервис и пришел к умозаключению что это самое лучшее решение для моей проблемы, но я плохо представляю как сервис будет перехватывать данные введенные пользователем и дальше хранить и использовать повторно.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services?hl=ru

Comment: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/162-urok-97-service-binding-serviceconnection.html

Comment: активити делает bindService, передавая туда интент для запуска сервиса и класс-коннектор. после этого сервис поднимается, в нём  вызывается onBind(), куда сервис кладёт класс, реализующий ваш интерфейс. интерфейс описывается в aidl. после этого класс-коннектор получает интерфейс сервиса в onServiceConnected. всё. можете использовать RPC-интерфейс. aidl файл нужно будет положить как в проект сервиса (если разные проекты), так и в проект активити. при сборке ide сгенерит соответствующие стабы, от которых нужно будет унаследоваться. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl